# url.pathname or url.searchParams is not a function in android react native

Tags: android, react-native, url

I am working on android react native project and i get URL for deep linking . I am trying to find the pathname and search parameters from the following url : https://test.xxx.com/test/test?test=moduleName .

var url = URL("https://test.xxx.com/test/test?test=moduleName");
console.log(url.pathName);

The code gives the following exception "Error: not implemented" . 
I also installed URL package from node . What am i missing ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at this [URL polyfill for React Native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-url-polyfill):

```
import { URL, URLSearchParams } from 'react-native-url-polyfill';

const url = new URL("https://test.xxx.com/test/test?test=moduleName");
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams('q=GitHub');
```

Please also note - [React Native runs within the JavascriptCore engine](https://reactnative.dev/docs/javascript-environment) while Node.js/Web run within the v8 Javascript engine.

Node.js provides its own proprietary functionality - streams, crypto, http, etc. This functionality is unavailable in React Native outside of third-party packages like [node-libs-react-native](https://github.com/parshap/node-libs-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for get url params without any libraries

```
export const getUrlParams = (url: string) => {
  const params: any = {};
  url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, (m, key, value) => {
    params[key] = value;
    return '';
  });
  return params;
};
```